# SUM specific set of values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I've been trying to look for a way to sum a specific set of values in a query.

Currently I have a query that returns all values needed, but I want it to now sum several values.

```
 |Name|Value|
 |x   |1    |
 |x   |2    |
 |x   |3    |
 |x   |5    |
 |y   |3    |
 |y   |2    |
 |y   |2    |
 |y   |3    |
 |z   |3    |
 |z   |2    |
 |z   |1    |
```

I don't know if I should run a subquery, I'm not necessarily summing up distinct values, but instead have something along the lines of this:

```
|Name|Value|
|x   |11   |
|y   |10   |
|z   |6    |
```

Although, each entry has their own unique ID for their respective row. I'm fairly new at this so I don't know if I would take that into account with my query.

Comment: why can't you just do a `select sum(Value) ... group by Name`?

Comment: There is a lot more to my select statement, there are more than two columns, a join, a date range, and an order by. I wanted to see how the sum works and build upon that in my query.

Comment: then you should put that into your question. we can't read your mind, after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select q.name, sum(q.value) 
from (YOUR_SELECT_QUERY) q
group by q.name
```

Answer (score 0):

A CTE might be the easiest way to go here:

```
;WITH CTE AS (Your Query Here)

SELECT Name, SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Name
```